# Congruences for "colored partitions" a la Ramanujan

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics

Let $t\in\Bbb{N}$ and consider the sequences $p_t(n)$ defined by
$$\sum_{n\geq0}p_t(n)x^n=\prod_{i\geq1}\frac1{(1-x^i)^t}=(x;x)_{\infty}^{-t}.$$
The numbers $p_t(n)$ can be regarded as enumerating *partitions of $n$ into parts of $t$ colors*.
Furthermore, $p_t(n)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\prod_{j\geq1}\binom{k_j+t-1}{t-1}$ where
$\lambda=1^{k_1}2^{k_2}\cdots$ and each $k_j\geq0$.

Note also that $p_1(n)=p(n)$ is the
usual unrestricted partition of $n$. Ramanujan's famous congruences state
$$\begin{cases}
 p(5n+4)\equiv0\mod 5, \\ p(7n+5)\equiv0\mod 7, \\ p(11n+6)\equiv0\mod 11. 
\end{cases}$$
Following this tradition, I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Do these congruences hold true?
> $$\begin{cases}
>  p_4(5n+4)\equiv0\mod 5, \\ p_4(7n+5)\equiv0\mod 7, \\ p_3(11n+7)\equiv0\mod 11. 
> \end{cases}$$

**POSTSCRIPT.** I thank Gjergji Zaimi for his response shown below. I now exhibit all the congruences that I have found. Let's see how many are already covered in the literature.
$$\begin{cases} p_t(5n+1)\equiv0\mod 5 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0\mod5$}, \\
p_t(5n+2)\equiv0\mod 5 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,2\mod5$}, \\
p_t(5n+3)\equiv0\mod 5 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,2,4\mod5$}, \\
p_t(5n+4)\equiv0\mod 5 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,1,2,4\mod5$}. \end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
p_t(7n+1)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,\mod7$}, \\
p_t(7n+2)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,4\mod7$}, \\
p_t(7n+3)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,6\mod7$}, \\
p_t(7n+4)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,4,6\mod7$}, \\
p_t(7n+5)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,1,4\mod7$}, \\
p_t(7n+6)\equiv0\mod 7 \qquad {} \text{if $t\equiv0,4,6\mod7$}. \end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}
p_t(11n+1)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+2)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,8\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+3)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,10\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+4)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,8\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+5)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,8\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+6)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,1,10\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+7)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,3,8\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+8)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,5,8,10\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+9)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,7,8,10\mod11$}, \\
p_t(11n+10)\equiv0\mod 11 \qquad\text{if $t\equiv0,10\mod11$}. \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, these are all true and they are all in the literature. The first two congruences are part of infinite families of the form
$$\begin{cases}
 p_{\ell-1}(\ell n+a)\equiv 0\mod \ell, \\ p_{\ell-3}(\ell n+b)\equiv0\mod \ell,
\end{cases}$$
where $\ell \geq 5$ is a prime and $a,b$ are such that: $24a+1$ is a quadratic nonresidue, $8b+1$ is either a quadratic nonresidue or divisible by $\ell$. Both congruences are immediate consequences of the Euler pentagonal theorem and Jacobi triple product respectively. This is explained in section 2 of the paper: I. Kiming and J. Olsson, *Congruences like Ramanujan's for powers of the partition function* (Arch. Math., 59(4):348-360, 1992) [doi: 10.1007/BF01197051](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01197051), where they are called the *non-exceptional* case.

The third identity is a bit more recent. It was proven in Lin, B.L.S. *Ramanujan-style proof of $p_{−3}(11n+7)≡0 \pmod{11}$* (Ramanujan J 42, 223–231 (2017)) [doi:10.1007/s11139-015-9733-5](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11139-015-9733-5). It was generalized to the following infinite family
$$p_{\ell-8}\left(\ell n+\frac{\ell^2-1}{3}-\ell \left\lfloor\frac{\ell^2-1}{3\ell}\right\rfloor\right)\equiv 0 \mod \ell.$$
For this last congruence and many other *exceptional* infinite families see the paper Locus, M., Wagner, I. *Congruences for Powers of the Partition Function* (Ann. Comb. 21, 83–93 (2017)) [doi:10.1007/s00026-017-0342-4](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00026-017-0342-4) arXiv:[1604.07495](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07495).

Comment: I think you mean $p_3(11n+7)\equiv0\mod 11$ and not $p_{-3}(11n+7)\equiv0\mod 11$. Right?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan Their notation is different from yours. But yes, in your notation it would be $p_3$.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan All the congruences you added in the postscript are either non-exceptional or covered by theorems 1 and 2 in Locus-Wagner, so none of them are new in that sense.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this.